# How to sort property from multiple objects

Tags: c#, sorting

I have some objects. And in each object there is a propety age. And I want to sort the property age  of all the objects. And in this case I have two objects. But for example if you have three, four..etc objects. Maybe there is a more generic method for this?

So this is the code:

```
List<Person> personList = new List<Person>
{

    new Person { Age = 77 },
    new Person { Age = 88 },
    new Person { Age = 1001 },
    new Person { Age = 755 }
};

List<Dog> dogList = new List<Dog>
{

    new Dog { Age = 1 },
    new Dog { Age = 9 },
    new Dog { Age = 10 },
    new Dog { Age = 8 }
};

personList.Sort((x, y) => x.Age.CompareTo(y.Age));
dogList.Sort((x, y) => x.Age.CompareTo(y.Age));
```

So the output has to be in this case:

> 1 8 9 10 77 88 755 1001

Comment: You can use quicksort or simply comparison based on ur required value and swap  items. Just search for `geeksforgeeks quicksort` or google

Comment: Do you just want to sort each list individually? Or get a single sorted list of all Age values from each list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create two lists of the ages which will create an `IEnumerable<int>`, and `Combine` and `Order` them...

```
var personAsAge = personList.Select(p => p.Age);
var dogAsAge = Dogist.Select(d => d.Age);

var ageOrder = personAsAge.Concat(dogAsAge).OrderBy(a => a);
```

You will need to import `System.Linq;` too.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Christian's approach of mutating / extending an existing list with `Concat`, it's also possible to do this without materializing the projections and using [`Union`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.union?view=net-5.0) to produce a new combined sequence, before ordering, like so:

```
var sortedAges = personList
    .Select(p => p.Age)
    .Union(dogList.Select(d => d.Age))
    .OrderBy(age => age);

foreach (var age in sortedAges) // << The result is only 'materialized' here, once.
{ ...
```

Comment: *it's also possible to do this without materializing the projections* - can you please give other readers (including me) a link to read up on this. Without adding a new question I'm interested in the way algorithms and data types are chosen depending on the LINQ. Thanks

Comment: Good point. I can't find an absolutely 'definitive' guide to lazy evaluation / aka deferred execution (suggest google around), but essentially IEnumerable and IQueryable enable 'stream' type processing, as opposed to concrete in memory processing (like a List, Array etc). There are pros and cons of either approach, but its always good to really know what's going on under the hood, especially when dealing with large data sources and also IQueryable sources like Entity Framework / ORMs, where materialization will actually execute a query on the database.